# .Net equivalent for the TTimer Delphi component

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

Exist a .net class equivalent to the [TTimer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TTimer) delphi component?

> TTimer is used to simplify calling the
>   Windows API timer functions SetTimer
>   and KillTimer, and to simplify
>   processing the WM_TIMER messages. Use
>   one timer component for each timer in
>   the application.
>
> The execution of the timer occurs
>   through its OnTimer event. TTimer has
>   an Interval property that determines
>   how often the timer's OnTimer event
>   occurs. Interval corresponds to the
>   parameter for the Windows API SetTimer
>   function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several!  The closest to the Delphi TTimer is probably [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), but there are also [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) for use in non-WinForms environments.

Answer (score 2):

Here's probably what you want:
[Timer Component (Windows Form)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1c2h276(VS.80).aspx)

And since there are more than only one Timer in .NET, here's a place where they compare them and explains the differences:
[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S1)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) will do what you want?

Edit: Sorry, I didn't realize that Stopwatch doesn't provide events. As itowlson mentioned, use System.Windows.Form.Timer or System.Threading.Timer.